# Maphilight перестаёт работать при замене ссылки

Tags: jquery, wordpress, javascript

http://tarasik78.tmweb.ru/p2860/ есть вот такая страничка, при этом при наведении на этаж должна включаться подсветка всего этажа как тут http://avenue-apart.ru/catalog/id/1/- так оно и работает пока в настройках wordpress не поменять со стандартных (http://tarasik78.tmweb.ru/?p=123) ссылок на название записи http://tarasik78.tmweb.ru/sample-post/ - после этого подсветка перестаёт работать- почему ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это у вас из-за особенностей кода плагина.
    <map name="rf">
<map name="image-maps-2014-07-03-180454" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-07-03-180454">
<area  alt="" title="1 этаж" href="http://tarasik78.tmweb.ru/?page_id=2886" shape="rect" coords="134,491,836,529" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="2 этаж" href="http://tarasik78.tmweb.ru/?page_id=2886" shape="rect" coords="136,447,838,485" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="" href="http://tarasik78.tmweb.ru/?page_id=2886" shape="rect" coords="133,399,836,440" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="4 этаж" href="http://tarasik78.tmweb.ru/?page_id=2886" shape="rect" coords="133,357,835,396" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="5 этаж" href="http://tarasik78.tmweb.ru/?page_id=2886" shape="rect" coords="135,311,837,354" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="" href="http://tarasik78.tmweb.ru/?page_id=2886" shape="rect" coords="134,275,839,310" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area shape="rect" coords="958,599,960,601" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />
</map>
<div class="social-bookmark"></div><div class="social-share"></div> 
</div><!-- #post-2860 -->

Планиг не расчитан на использование ЧПУ